# Dynamic UIView height with auto layout in iOS 6

Tags: objective-c, ios6, autolayout

For the last couple of days I am trying to accomplish a fairly simple (at least it should be) layout using auto layout constraints, but without success.

*My view hierarchy is:*
UIScrollView
-- UIView (Container view)
-----UILabel (Multirow label)
-----UIWebView
-----UILabel
-----UIButton

[image: View hierarchy in IB]

The desired functionallity is the Container view to be expanding according to the size of the contents. In order to increase the height of the UIWebView I use the following code:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    [self.webView sizeToFit];
}
```

I tried many different constraints, with the most reasonable ones being:
1. Pin top space from superview for the 1st label (Event Title)
2. Pin vertical spacing for the 1st label and the UIWebView
3. Pin vertical spacing for the rest elements (i.e. UIWebView - UILabel (Event Date) and UILabel (Event Date) - UIButton)
4. The container view has low priority (1) bottom vertical space constraint with its superview

The result I get is the following:
[image]

The UIWebView expands but does not push down the event date label and the button, plus the Container view does not expand either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

You may download the sample Xcode project [from here.](http://nsloom.com/downloads/AutoLayoutDemo.zip)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You are setting the height contraint of your webView as 266. That's why the height of the web view is still fixed.

You can create this height constraint as an IBOutlet, for example:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *webViewHeightConstraint;
```

And then you can modify the constant of the height constraint when the web view has finished downloading the content. The web view itself consists of scroll view inside, so if you want to get the overall height of the content:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    self.webViewHeightConstraint.constant = self.webView.scrollView.contentSize.height;
}
```

Or apparently this one also works:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    [self.webView sizeToFit];
    self.webViewHeightConstraint.constant = self.webView.frame.size.height;
}
```

Comment: I wish I could upvote this a million times...  Your answer just ended 4 hours of banging my head on my keyboard.

Comment: I have a much simpler problem and just can't get it working. It's just a `Label` in a `Content View` in a `Scroll View` in the "main" `View` and I do as you say I set the constraint to the `label.frame.size.height` but it's not working. As I understand the `contentSize` should "grow" automatically.Code here: http://loessl.org/~hashier/relpub_2/DynLabel.zip

Comment: I'd suggest that you don't use sizeToFit. Instead, use intrinsicContentSize. If the object you are using doesn't return the correct intrinsic content size, as is the case in UITextView for example, make a simple subclass and override that method to return something appropriate, i.e. sizeThatFits, or contentSize. Don't forget to call invalidateIntrinsicContentSize when this changes!

Comment: I also added my view as a delegat of itself `[self.webViewSummary setDelegate:self];` and in the .h file `@interface dphDetailsViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>` so I didn't have to write a new class just to resize the webview.

Comment: And what about rotations? In portrait I get content 1000pt height. The I rotate in landscape, but the height of the WebView is fixed with the height-constraint. It seems that the only way is recalculate height and change height-constraint at willLayoutSubviews

Comment: I search a lot in stackoverflow, but almost of them said about remove Auto Layout that will effect throught all storyboard. This one is really work!

Answer (score 1):

You might need a delay before updating webview content size. And [masonry](https://github.com/SnapKit/Masonry) is useful for autolayout usage.

```
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webview{
    [self performSelector:@selector(checkContentOnDelay:) withObject:webview afterDelay:0.001];
}

-(void)checkContentOnDelay:(UIWebView *)webview{
    CGSize contentSize = webview.scrollView.contentSize;
    if (contentSize.height > 2) {
        [webview updateConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
            make.height.equalTo(contentSize.height);
        }];
    }else{
        [self performSelector:@selector(checkContentOnDelay:) withObject:webview afterDelay:0.01];
    }
}
```