# UIView sizing programmatically

Tags: swift, uiview

I have an UIView with two containers in IB with two filter buttons (one is up and one is down). I have created two functions called filterUP and filterDOWN and they work like this :

```
    @IBAction func FilterDown(sender: AnyObject) {

    self.FilterDownButton.hidden = true
    var duration = 0.5
    self.FilterView.clipsToBounds = true
    UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, animations: {

        self.FilterView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 65, width: 375, height: 195)



        }, completion: { finished in


            self.FilterUPButton.hidden = false
            self.FilterDownButton.hidden = false



    })
```

And what it does is animate the filter UIView up and down. which is fine and they work.

When the app starts I want the UIView (filter) at CGRect(x: 0, y: 65, width: 375, height: 65) - i.e. hidden only 20 high.

So I did

```
self.view.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:65, width: 375, height: 20)
```

in viewDidLoad.

This has not done anything and the UIView is still full size when the app runs. 
I have toggled with AutoLayout (On/Off) and Size Classes (on/Off) and this does not work.

How can I get the UIView a certain size when the app starts up ?

Comment: use auto layout, don't mess with frames thats old school.

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1

Comment: ok, I use auto layout thats cool, but why doesn't my self.view.frame work in the view controller to make the view smaller when the app runs ?

Comment: Because you are not using Auto Layout. If you want to manipulate the size of a view you need to change the constraints, see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17510135/dynamic-uiview-height-with-auto-layout-in-ios-6