# UIImageView - move content up if image height is small

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I've got a UIImageView in my app and would like to move content up if the image height is small. Here's an ASCII example - each line is say 50 or 100 pixels in the app:

Full height image:

```
[  
    UIIMAGEVIEW 
]
    CONTENT
```

Short image:

```
[  UIIMAGEVIEW ] 


    CONTENT
```

Is it possible to have the UIImageView height shrink somehow so that the content is always adjacent (like DIVs in HTML)?

At the moment I'm using a fixed height constraint in Auto Layout.

Do I need to add an IBOutlet and then adjust the constraint in code like this: [Dynamic UIView height with auto layout in iOS 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17510135/dynamic-uiview-height-with-auto-layout-in-ios-6). Seems rather long-winded if so.

Comment: I think you just need delete that fixed height constraint.

Comment: I deleted the fixed height constraint and got a red Missing Constraints icon suggesting I add another 7 constraints to make things work. Looking at the Height Constraint itself it shows it to be a Constant of 200. I can't seem to be able to change this to non-Constant.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, Get image's size like mentioned below and set width/height of UIImageView for them. Then subtract new height of UIImageView from old height, and subtract then subtract this result from .y of your content view.

```
float heightOfImage = image.size.height;
```